# PHP - Tidy - Keep none HTML Tag

Tags: php, tidy

I need to clean an html string but I need to keep a custom tagin it , like :

```
<CUSTOM_TAG/>
```

I use 'tidy_repair_string()' php function.

```
$str = '<div><CUSTOM_TAG/><br><span>my little html</span></div>';
$tidy_config = array();
$tidy_text = tidy_repair_string($str, $tidy_config, 'utf8');
```

I didn't find any [Tidy options](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html) which can help me. Any idea ?

In advance, Thanks.

---

### I'VE FOUND THE SOLUTION :

The Tidy option you need to use is : " 'input-xml' => true ".
Thank you all for your investigation !!

Comment: in your example, the desired output would be `<CUSTOM_TAG/>my little html` or just `<CUSTOM_TAG/>`?

Comment: This HTML has to be valid and other stuff. So I need to keep my CUSTOM_TAG into the tidy HTML.

Comment: then please provided a couple of examples of input => desired output, please.

Comment: Input : '<div><h1><CUSTOM_TAG id="487"/><br><span>my little html</span></div><a/>'
// Ouput : '<div><CUSTOM_TAG id="487"/><br><span>my little html</span></div>'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Tidy option you need to use is : " 'input-xml' => true ". Thank you all for your investigation !!

Answer (score 0):

[`strip_tags( )`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) should be able to do what you want. You can give it a list of tags to skip.

Example:

```
$str = '<div><CUSTOM_TAG/><br><span>my little html</span></div>';
$tidy_text = strip_tags( $str, "<CUSTOM_TAG>" );
```

Comment: As I've said on top of the page, I need to tidy my HTML + keep custom tags.

Answer (score 0):

You need to teach Tidy that the `<CUSTOM_TAG>` is valid by specifying the [`new-blocklevel-tags`](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html#new-blocklevel-tags) configuration option. You probably also need to add it to [`new-empty-tags`](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html#new-empty-tags) to make it accept it without content or attributes, it will probably strip it away otherwise.

Comment: I've tried to do it:
    $tidy_config = array('new-blocklevel-tags' => 'CUSTOM_TAG', 'new-  empty-tags' => 'CUSTOM_TAG');
Seems no working...

Comment: If I try it online with http://infohound.net/tidy it only accepts the custom tag if specified in lower case. When I enter `CUSTOM_TAG` in caps it *still strips it*.

Comment: There's also a surplus space in `new- empty-tags` in your code sample btw.

Comment: Yes, it was a wrong copy / paste. In my code there's no space. But thanks for your notice.